# How do I obtain a domain name for the 'flutter create' cmd?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter and I want to know how to get a domain name to create a project in Flutter. I know it is not essential to start but I want to save my future self from having to change it. Do I create a domain using google?

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more? What do you mean by domain name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you are talking about so called [Application ID](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set_the_application_id) for Android / [Bundle ID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/bundle_ids) for iOS.

If you are creating app for some company I would suggest to call it according to it's name.
For example if you are creating new app for Google and it's name gonna be Ab Cd I'd call it something like **com.google.abcd**.

For private purposes usually just use anything you like. I prefer using something like **com.moria.app_name_goes_here**.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that was what I was talking about. So the application ID doesn't have to be unique?